# How to install helm in travis pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, kubernetes-helm, helm-tls

I am doing this to install helm in my travis job

```
curl https://baltocdn.com/helm/signing.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https --yes
echo "deb https://baltocdn.com/helm/stable/debian/ all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/helm-stable-debian.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install helm
```

And when the command ***helm init --client-only*** runs in the travis, it says

```
Not Really a helm install
```

Can someone help me out in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command is the correct way to install helm in the Travis pipeline:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3 | bash
```

And then you can check by using

```
helm version
```

Comment: Yes, you can `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3 | bash` if you want to live on the edge :) ( https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/#from-script ).

Answer (score 1):

As [Installing Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install) chapter from the **official Helm guide** says:

> 1. Download your desired version from [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases)
> 2. Unpack it (`tar -zxvf helm-v3.0.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz`)
> 3. Find the helm binary in the unpacked directory, and move it to its desired destination (`mv Linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm`).
>
> From there, you should be able to run the client and [add the stable repo](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/quickstart/#initialize-a-helm-chart-repository) : `helm help`

Comment: Hi, Rahil.
It's not the correct way. I found the answer to it and will post it.
The steps you described are to install helm in your local machine.